# Return Multiple Data from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-activity

I'm trying to organize my app code separating AsyncTask classes from Activity or Fragments.
Surfing this forum I've learned about the "interface and listener" solution:

**Interface.java**

```
public interface TaskCompleteListener<T> {
    public void onTaskComplete(T result);
}
```

**AsyncTask.java**

```
[...]
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String JSONResponse) {
    // using Gson library I convert JSONResponse string to POJO objects...
    listener.onTaskComplete(result);
}
```

**Activity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // start AsyncTask...
    }

    // Inner class implementing interface
    public class LoadTaskCompleteListener implements TaskCompleteListener<Object> {
        @Override
        public void onTaskComplete(Object result) {
            updateUI(result);
        }
    }

    public void updateUI(Object result) {
    // here you can manage UI updating, using result object
    }
}
```

UPDATE
**DataHelper.java**

```
public class DataHelper {

    private AsyncTaskCompleteListener<Object> listener;

    public DataHelper(AsyncTaskCompleteListener<Obejct> listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    // Multiple AsyncTask are defined here...
}
```

Well, I like this pattern so much, but: what if inside activity (or fragment)
I have **multiple requests**, with different type of results (single object, array, list)
and different business logic for managing them?
**I can't handle that using a single callback**. Any ideas? Should I add multiple
callbacks inside the interface? I'm really stuck with this.
I've a single file called DataHelper with multiple AsyncTask inside (something like web getters).
Naturally I can give up with this approach if you suggest any other alternative.

Comment: Can you post code where you initiate `listener`?

Comment: See UPDATE edit. I pass it to DataHelper constructor, a convenience class for data retrieval purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the definition of `onTaskComplete()` accepts as argument a generic type, type `T`:

```
 onTaskComplete(T result);
```

this means that you can pass in any object type, single object, array, list, etc.

Regarding on how to handle different results using a single callback, you can use a `Bundle` to put the result in, associated with a key, and then in `updateUI()` check for that key and take appropriate actions.

Something like this (pseudocode, not sure if it will compile):

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String JSONResponse) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("key_json_response", result); //put the response in a Bundle
    listener.onTaskComplete(bundle);
}

// .....
public void updateUI(Object result) {
   Bundle bundle = (Bundle)result;
   if(bundle.containsKey("key_json_response")){
     String json = bundle.getString("key_json_response");
     // process json
   } else if(bundle.containsKey("key_another_response")){
     // process another response
   } 
}
```

Comment: Sounds good...I was just trying to avoid moving business logic like JSON parsing to activity, providing it ready to use objects.

Comment: There's nothing that would stop you from doing this. You can parse the json in the `onPostExecute()` and then put the ready to use object in the `Bundle`, instead of putting the `String` json response. You can use the `Bundle` to put in any primitive data types, as well as custom objects, if they implements `Serializable`.

Comment: You're correct. I've used bundle.putSerializable method to pass a generic Bundle object. Is it better to use Parcelable interface? In general do you think that my code organization approach will work quiet good?

Comment: In general `Parcelable` is recommended in favor of `Serializable`, main gain being the speed. However, using `Serializable` is much simpler. Yes, the approach of using an interface to deliver results from an `AsyncTask` is good.

Answer (score 1):

Why not return an array of Objects as a result? Then if you have more than one object inside that array you'll know the order in which you put them so you can use more than one set of results at a time.

```
public interface TaskCompleteListener<T> {
    public void onTaskComplete(T... results);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, interesting idea, but that way I've to wait for all requests to finish, before I can handle results, am I right?

Comment: If you return them all at once like this then yes, you have to wait for all of them to complete.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a 'handler' can be used instead of an async task and that each handler may return its message to the message looper with the msg wrapping different data. Easy to handle many data types because its just a message component. 
 Sample [here](http://masl.cis.gvsu.edu/2010/04/05/android-code-sample-asynchronous-http-connections/)

See 'process_entity() ' where the messages containing result component are sent by sample code.

Comment: Handler is sending back a string, can i send "complex" objects too?

Comment: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/BinaryHttpResponseHandler.html

Comment: See binary data sample . complex objects would need to be parcelable in order to be included I believe.